# Exoplayer Android - start download of progressive MP3 whilst another MP3 is playing

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hopefully my request/question makes sense. im new to audio streaming and the Exoplayer API. as such I'm hoping some Exoplayer guru's can help me out !

what we'd like to do is :

1. start playing an MP3 track (using **progressive** download).
2. after "X" seconds (where "X" differs from song to song) we need to **pause** the above track and then play a different MP3 file (that contains an ad)
3. after the audio ad completes, resume playing the track from (1) above

what we are currently doing is this:

a) pause the MP3 track from (1) above <- uses "exoPlayer_1" instance

b) launch a NEW / have a second Exoplayer instance available, which is  responsible for playing the ad <- uses "exoPlayer_2" instance

c) resume the MP3 track from (1) above once the ad had finished playing

Or is there a better way to do this using some of the many Exoplayer API's that appear to be available ?

We're using their Kotlin API's. I could post code here but its pretty much the boilerplate from the ExoPlayer code lab at this point.

Really appreciate any help/advice on this, thanks

Comment: what exactly is the issue, you are getting?

Comment: thanks @Arsal . its not so much an issue, it is more a question. which boils down to "is there a better way to do this" ?